# Can Android run on an iPad?

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

Can Android run on an iPad ?

1. Please answer only if you are 100% sure (or even better if you tried)
2. If yes, should I use a jailbreaker ? Could you suggest me one ?
3. If yes, what are the limitations.. are the applications running on it without issues ?
4. If not, why... is there a good tablet to test Android applications ?

thanks

Comment: It's possible on the iPhone, it should happen with the iPad eventually: http://www.taranfx.com/android-on-iphone

Comment: "is there a good tablet to test Android applications ?" -- any Android tablet would be a better platform to test Android applications than would a hacked iPad. You want your test equipment to match what consumers will use. There will be a few orders of magnitude more users of a Samsung Galaxy Tab, for example, than will be running Android on an iPad.

Comment: Note that once you have Android running on one of these Apple devices the major problem is that they only have one button, and almost every Android app assumes that you have "Home", "Back" and "Menu" buttons at a minimum. You are much better off testing Android apps on a tablet designed for Android like Dell Streak or Samsung Galaxy Tab (and they're generally cheaper than an equivalent iPad).

Comment: @GAThrawn thanks, yeah that's true, they are cheaper, but I actually would love to test all software on only one device.. (because of my wallet)

Comment: You would need two devices anyway. Once you converted an iPad to Android, it would (probably) never again run iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem as thought it has only so far been developed to be booted on iPhone 2G and 3G devices. It's mostly up to the interest of keen developers whether it would be worthwhile attempting such a feat, I would assume whatever exploit used to run Android on otherwise locked down Apple hardware would be different in later hardware (yes, this means an iPad).

"Please answer only if you are 100% sure" - Then yes, an iPad **COULD** theoretically run Android because of the open source nature of Android allowing it to be ported to various devices. Anything is possible when you put your mind to it, it's looking at the realistic feasibility and time vs reward involved though.